# CSS Media Queries Not Reverting

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a div without content to simulate a link break when the screen is smaller than 800 pixels, and it works fine when I shrink the browser down, but when I enlarge it again, the div is still simulating a line break rather than not displaying, and I don't know why it isn't working.

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="container-row">
            <div id="container-current">
                    <!-- Sets up the container for the video -->
                <video id="current-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
                controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto"
                data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }'>
                        <!-- Location of the video -->
                    <source src="sun1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
                </video>
                        <!-- Location of the video -->
                    <source src="sun1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                </video>
            </div>

            <div id="container-inactive">
                <div class="image-row">
                        <div class="image-cell">
                            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/NpEaa2P7qZI/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Placeholder">
                        </div>

                        <div class="image-cell">
                            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/NpEaa2P7qZI/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Placeholder">
                        </div>

                        <div class="image-break"></div>

                        <div class="image-cell">
                            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/NpEaa2P7qZI/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Placeholder">
                        </div>

                        <div class="image-cell">
                            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/NpEaa2P7qZI/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Placeholder">
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


.video-js .vjs-tech {
    height:100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
}

body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:black;
}

#container {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#container-current {
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#container-inactive {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:10px 30px;
}

.image row {
    display:table-row;
}

.image-cell {
    display:table-cell;
}

.image-cell img {
    width:100%;
}

.image-break {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .image-break {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

For video display, I am using [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/)

Comment: Can you provide your css? Ideally all your code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Make sure you don't have any !important; 
I've had issues with it in the past.

Comment: @Guy Scroll down, the CSS is there. @Chrillewoodz I do, but they aren't related to the media query, would that still cause a problem? @Pangloss, I do have a opening tag for `<video>`, I fixed the `.image-row` in my CSS, and the `.image-break` does change from `display:none;` to `display:block;` when the browser size is reduced, it just does not go BACK to `display:none;` when I enlarge the screen again. At any rate, it won't matter anyway because I am going to completely change the way I am doing the images.

Comment: OK I see it's not missing the opening video tag it's actually doubled closing tag. As I said not matter the div is block or none it won't take any effect in table cells. Describe what you want to have.

Comment: My best guess - [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8o62zz4/) shows how to do it in the common way.